# Where is the Google Play Developer Console 'Save' button

Tags: android, developer-console

I dont care if this gets down voted, as long as someone can explain to me where the save button is in the google play developer console. I updated store listing by changing the icon. I just want to save these changes without uploading the new version of the app by clicking 'Submit Update'. A screenshot will do. :D Thanks

Comment: there is no 'save' without submitting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 3):

You have to click `Submit Update`. Submitting listing updates doesn't mean you have to upload a new APK, so don't think of it as necessarily submitting a new app version.

Comment: :| ok, thankyou. Still new to using the google play dev console

Comment: Same issue.  I thought "submit update" was for the app and not the settings for the app.  Google's instructions say "click save".